# Excel VBA - convert range with pictures and buttons to HTML

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a function that turns an excel range into HTML for further use in an email body. The problem is that I now want to add pictures and buttons to the range and have it then taken over into the email body.

How I can get excel to address objects in the range and convert them over as well?

Thanks

Function Range to HTML

```
    Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2013
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook


    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"


    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With


    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With


    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")


    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False


    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile


    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Copy the range and the object to a new workbook and then save the workbook as an html

Comment: That would give me a html file, what I need is the html code if the range content which I then use in an emails body.

Comment: Yes when you copy only selected range+object to a new workbook and save it as html then you get an html for only that. Read the html file in a string and then set the  `.HTMLBody` to that string.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comments above, copy the range and the object to a new workbook and then save the workbook as an html. Read the html file in a string and then set the `.HTMLBody` to that string after making a slight change.

**Important**:

1. Save the html file in an empty folder. I pasted the excel file which contains the code and data in an empty folder.
2. Tested in Excel 2013

Let's say our workbook looks like this

[image]

See the code below. I have commented the code so you should not have a problem understanding it. Still if you do then post back.

**Code**:

```
Option Explicit

'~~> This is the temp html file name.
'~~> Do not change this as when you publish the
'~~> html file, it will create a folder Temp_files
'~~> to store the images
Const tmpFile As String = "Temp.Htm"

'~~> Do not change "Myimg". This will be used to
'~~> identify the images
Const imgPrefix As String = "Myimg"

Sub Sample()
    Dim wbThis As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim tempFileName As String, imgName As String, newPath As String

    Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add

    '~~> Copy the relevant range to new workbook
    wbThis.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J17").Copy _
    wbNew.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

    newPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    tempFileName = newPath & tmpFile

    '~~> Publish the image
    With wbNew.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, _
        tempFileName, "Sheet1", "$A$1:$J$17", xlHtmlStatic, _
        imgPrefix, "")
        .Publish (True)
        .AutoRepublish = True
    End With

    '~~> Close the new file without saving
    wbNew.Close (False)

    '~~> Read the html file in a string in one go
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Open tempFileName For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

    '~~> Loop through the file
    For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
        '~~> Here we will first get the image names
        If InStr(1, strData(i), "Myimg_", vbTextCompare) And InStr(1, strData(i), ".Png", vbTextCompare) Then
            '~~> Insert actual path to the images
            strData(i) = Replace(strData(i), "Temp_files/", newPath & "Temp_files\")
        End If
    Next i

    '~~> Rejoin to get the new html string
    MyData = Join(strData, vbCrLf)

    '~~> Create the Email
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = "Email address Goes here"
        .Subject = "Subject Goes here"

        '~~> Set the body
        .HTMLBody = MyData

        '~~> Show the email. Change it to `.Send` to send it
        .Display
    End With

    '~~> Delete the temp file name
    Kill tempFileName
End Sub
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

Converted it to a **Function**

```
Option Explicit

Private Function RngToEmail(rng As Range, eTo As String, eSubject As String)
    Dim wbThis As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim tempFileName As String, imgName As String, newPath As String

    '~~> Do not change "Myimg". This will be used to
    '~~> identify the images
    Dim imgPrefix As String: imgPrefix = "Myimg"

    '~~> This is the temp html file name.
    '~~> Do not change this as when you publish the
    '~~> html file, it will create a folder Temp_files
    '~~> to store the images
    Dim tmpFile As String: tmpFile = "Temp.Htm"

    Set wbThis = Workbooks(rng.Parent.Parent.Name)
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add

    '~~> Copy the relevant range to new workbook
    rng.Copy wbNew.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

    newPath = wbThis.Path & "\"
    tempFileName = newPath & tmpFile

    '~~> Publish the image
    With wbNew.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, _
        tempFileName, "Sheet1", Rng.Address, xlHtmlStatic, _
        imgPrefix, "")
        .Publish (True)
        .AutoRepublish = True
    End With

    '~~> Close the new file without saving
    wbNew.Close (False)

    '~~> Read the html file in a string in one go
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Open tempFileName For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

    '~~> Loop through the file
    For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
        '~~> Here we will first get the image names
        If InStr(1, strData(i), "Myimg_", vbTextCompare) And InStr(1, strData(i), ".Png", vbTextCompare) Then
            '~~> Insert actual path to the images
            strData(i) = Replace(strData(i), "Temp_files/", newPath & "Temp_files\")
        End If
    Next i

    '~~> Rejoin to get the new html string
    MyData = Join(strData, vbCrLf)

    '~~> Create the Email
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .to = eTo
        .subject = eSubject

        '~~> Set the body
        .HTMLBody = MyData

        '~~> Show the email. Change it to `.Send` to send it
        .Display
    End With

    '~~> Delete the temp file name
    Kill tempFileName
End Function
```

**Usage**:

```
Sub Sample()
    RngToEmail ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J17"), "someemail@someserver.com", "Some Subject"
End Sub
```

Comment: that is an excellent sample for me to study, thank you. My only question is why did you manually define range A1:J17 in the Function under "Publishing the image"? Shouldnt this range be defined dynamically via the range given upon the function call?

Comment: Also, the range is shown in the email body as centered and with different column widths / row heights. Is there a way to keep the original formatting of the selected range?

Comment: Yes you are right. I missed that. Just replace `"$A$1:$J$17"` with `rng.Address` in the funciton. Regarding the col width and formatting I am sure that can be customized as well :)